# Buffer typescript to byte[] C#

Tags: c#, file, typescript, byte, buffer

I'm trying to send a Buffer[] from typescript to a endpoint in C#, that manipulate the file received, like this:

.TS:

```
let goiaba = new Buffer("I'm a string!", "utf-8")
params.path = "File/UploadSync2";
let path = params.getRequestParams();
let uri = `${this.baseUrl}/${path}`;
let options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: uri,
  headers: params.header,
  form: {goiaba}
};
options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
return requestAsync.postAsync(options);
```

C# endpoint:

```
public Result<PutObjectResponse> UploadSync2(byte[] goiaba)
{
   return null;
}
```

The problem is that goiaba is receiving {byte[0]}.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Just a stab, but have you tried changing the parameter to `string goiaba`?

Comment: Yes, but without success

Comment: This is not TypeScript related.

Comment: I know it... Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `postAsync` is actually using Ajax maybe by changing `form: {goiaba}` to `data: goiaba` could make this work